# "Extend" Struct in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, extend

I say "extend" because after a google search I'm not sure that is the proper name for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Basically what I'm trying to do is create a struct (just for fun, let's also include classes in this question) with some blank variables in it, then make another struct or class that carries on where the parent left off, filling in those variables.

So something like this:

```
struct parent{

    int foo;
    int bar;
};

struct daughter : parent{
    foo=1;
    bar=3;
};

struct son : parent {
    foo=10;
    bar=20;

    int foobar;
};
```

and later on, I might need to branch out this tree further:

```
struct grandson : son {
    foo=50;
    bar=900;
    foobar=10000;
};
```

What would be the correct way to go about this?

EDIT:

@Everyone:
So, I can explain what I'm trying to do, and you can counter it with better ways, and who knows, maybe those ways are much better. However, first, right off the bat, I'm just curious if what I'm asking is possible...

And something I left out:

```
struct parent{
    int foo;
    int bar;
    int foobar;

    int add(int x, int y){
        return x+y;
    };

struct son : parent {
    foo=12;
    bar=13;
    foobar=add(foo,bar);
}
```

Comment: The notion of a "blank variable" just baffles me.

Comment: @AnOptionalName: Do you know the difference of struct and instance [of struct]? You´re asking about inheritance, but it looks like you want just some variables if the struct type...

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Blank variables can be very useful in what I'm trying to do. For example, in a game, create a blank monster class with certain variable initialized, then a bunch of sub classes with differences, like name/power etc.

Comment: @AnOptionalName: If the general monster won´t use a variable, just don´t define it there. That´s inheritance too...

Comment: @deviantfan: That's why I'm not sure if inheritance is the right word

Comment: @AnOptionalName. It´s "a" right word; but I still don´t know what you really want. Now a small test program would help to show.

Comment: Funny how people ask what I think are really noobish questions and show terrible programming style but then go on to write the most awesome games in the process!

Comment: @AnOptionalName: "blank variables" is not the usual C++ term though - based on your question, it seems to you are talking about (initially) "uninitialised" variables, in that the base class/struct doesn't set their values, leaving that for derived classes to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you may want to use constructors to initialize values like that.  Something like this:

```
struct daughter : public parent {
   daughter() {
      foo=1;
      bar=3;
   }
};
```

(btw I know the 'public' keyword isn't necessary, I included it only because I like to keep my intent explicit; otherwise I always wonder later if I just forgot to specify it)

Comment: Noob question- How would I initialize this in a header? `struct son;` gives an error, as does `struct son : parent;`

Comment: @AnOptionalName Also **note** `struct son : public /* <<<<<*/ parent;`

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner It seems the personal who asked the question has not little experience in C++. For safe of those people to learn the 'best' thing out of all possibilities, I would like to suggest you to introduce initializaion list in constructor instead of just assigning them in the contructor body.

Comment: @AnOptionalName: `struct son;` just repeats the type without actually naming a variable to be *of* that type... type `son a_son;` to create a variable called `a_son`.  A buy a C++ book ;-P.

Comment: Lmao ok. Gotta finish that c++ course now that its summer. Thanks

Comment: @AnOptionalName: it depends what you mean by "work"... `struct foo;` "declares" that there's a structure called `foo`.  If you make such a declaration, you can do limited things with the `struct` - for example declare a function with a `foo*` or `foo&` parameter - even before the `foo` definition is seen by the compiler (the definition is the `struct foo { ... };` code).  `struct foo;` does not create any variables.

Comment: @SargiEran C++ does not allow you to set a member variable of the superclass from the subclass's initialization-list.  (I suppose the "proper C++ way" might be to pass values for foo and bar as arguments to a two-argument constructor in the base class, and have that base-class constructor initialize them with an initialization-list, but I think that might be too much to digest at once for someone who is still just figuring out the basics of inheritance)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Exactly. I meant we have to introduce them in base class constructor. Sorry for misleading. Ultimately, I just wanted to mention something like,

struct parent{
private:
    int foo;
    int bar;
public:
    parent(int _foo, int _bar):foo(_foo), bar(_bar){}
};

struct daughter : parent{
public:
    daughter(int _foo, int _bar): parent(_foo, _bar){}
};

However, now those are in other answers as well

Answer (score 3):

Your `parent` and `daughter` are essentially the same type besides their initial class values. The same goes for `grandson` and `son`.

Why not use a constructor for that task?

```
struct parent
{
    parent () : foo(), bar() {}
    parent (int the_foo, int the_bar) 
      : foo(the_foo), bar(the_bar) {}
    int foo;
    int bar;
};

struct son : public parent
{
    son () : parent(10,20), foobar(foo+bar) {}
    son (int the_foobar) 
      : parent(10,20), foobar(the_foobar) {}
    int foobar;
}

int main ()
{
  parent p;
  parent daughter(1,3);
  son s;
  son grandson(10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, structs are treated as classes where all members are public by default.

So you can get the behaviour you are wanting.

However, you need to use a constructor to initialize the variables, you can't do it directly like you have written.

So this:

```
struct parent{
int foo;
int bar;
int foobar;

int add(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
};

struct son : parent {
foo=12;
bar=13;
foobar=add(foo,bar);
```

Needs to be written as

```
struct parent
{
  int foo;
  int bar;
  int foobar;

  int add(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
  };
};

struct son : parent 
{
  son()
  {
    foo = 12;
    bar = 13;
    foobar = add(foo,bar);
    // or just: foobar = foo+bar;
  }
};
```

But in this case, a son and a parent are actually an instantiation of the same struct.  Which is rather silly.  Are you going to be adding more fields to son because that's what inheritance is about.  In your case your father and son are identical but just hold different state.  On the other hand if son needs to hold other data then it needs to inherit.

Also, if you're going to start treating structs as classes by adding methods then why not just make them classes.

Comment: My personal opinion is to use structs for data storage and **very** small/simple methods

Comment: It's up to you what you do.  But I usually make them classes if I have methods.  Sometimes I'll leave them as structs if they have just a simple constructor.  But beyond that, I make them classes (even though they actually already are classes).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a necessity for inheritance in this case. If you just want to get instances of `parent` with specific values, then a simple function may be all that you need:

```
parent get_daughter() {
    // note that this syntax requires c++11
    // in earlier standards you may want to add a constructor to the class
    return {1, 3};
};
```

`son` introduces a new member so inheritance is appropriate.

Comment: Even though you're correct, the value of Q&A is that others may find an answer to the same question.  This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @SephReed It is useful to not only answer the question that was asked, but also address the problem that the asker tries to solve. If the problem instigated OP to ask this question, then others with the same problem may also end up here when searching for the same question. That is the value of Q&A. See also: http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

I think languages like java and C# may have some wage definitions of local object initialization. But, according to me C++ has got the 'best' way of explain member variable (not static) initialization. Just do them inside of constructors. Very clear, intuitive and less error-prone.

Answer (score -2):

- **Don't** use a `struct` for inheritance: use a `class` instead. This undermines the protection level in the inheritance hierarchy because the default privacy level of members of a struct is **public**.  C programmers reading C++ code will assume the structs aren't inherited, have methods, ETC.

Make all members private (if not modified by an inherited class) or protected (if modified by an inherited class) to prevent accidental modifications by the instantiators of the class.

Make the constructors `public` in order for the classes to be instantiated, if the classes are supposed to be instantiable by any other code.

```
class parent{

protected:
    int foo;
    int bar;
public:
    parent() {
        foo = 0;
        bar = 0;
    }
};

class daughter : parent{
private:
public:
    daughter() {
        foo=1;
        bar=3; 
    }
};

class son : parent {
private:
    int foobar;
public:
    son () {
        foo=10;
        bar=20;
        foobar = 0;
    }
};
```